# ReplaceAll со всеми символами кроме пятизначного числа

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка

```
String string = "12345jghdi6h90";
```

Как можно убрать из нее все символы кроме пятизначного числа в начале с помощью `replaceAll`?

Answer (score 0):

Если все равно какое число в начале(значность), то используем следующий вариант:

```java
String s = "12345jghdi6h90";
s = s.replaceAll("^(\\d+)[\\s\\S]*$","$1");
```

Если в начале должно быть только 5-значное число(к примеру, 6-значное обрезается), то такой вариант

```java
s = s.replaceAll("^(\\d{5})[\\s\\S]*$","$1");
```

`[\\s\\S]` - используется вместо `.`, чтобы обрезать строки с символом `\n` (`"12345jgh\nnni6h90"`)

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, вопрос простой и ответ простой. Что бы вы добавили?

Comment: @TigerTV.ru, у вас квантификатор `+` что означает 1 и более совпадений, в вопросе указано первое 5-тизначное число, возможно об этой развернутости ответа писал aleksandrbarakin.

Comment: @PotroNik, добавил пояснения

Answer (score -1):

```
String string = "12345jghdi6h90";

Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(\\d{5})([\\d\\w]*)").matcher(string);
matcher.find();
string = string.replaceAll(matcher.group(2),"");
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Пожалуйста, оставляйте более развёрнутые ответы: постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию, изложите свои предложения. Возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше. Дополнить ответ можно, нажав "править" https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score -1):

Не нужен он тут, всё делается проще:

```
String string = "12345jghdi6h90";
string = string.substring(0, 5);
```